# OSM To Postgis & WGS84 Newbie confusion

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openstreetmap

I wonder if someone can clarify as I'm confused.

I need to load planet OSM data into PostGIS so I downloaded a small data set of a UK County and followed [the instructions here](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=loading_osm_postgis)  loading the Google Mercator projection 900931.sql first.

looking at the data in GeoServer the co-ordinate readout on the location bar appears to be in metric East / West and not Longitude/Latitude yet the [osm wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WGS_84) states World Geodetic System 1984 is the coordinate system of OSM data.

What am I doing wrong?

Also is there a best practice for displaying OSM as a base layer?

Where can I get a Point.sld from?

Comment: check some coordinates in your nodes table - do they look like they are decimal degrees between +/- 180 / +/- 90? GeoServer may be projecting the data as it's rendered because of your layer configuration or WMS URL parameters

Answer (score 4):

OpenStreetMap stores data in WGS84 coordinates.
You can check this by downloading the XML data for any OSM node:

```
 $ curl "http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/327031143"
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <osm version="0.6" generator="OpenStreetMap server">
   <node id="327031143" lat="44.4795174" lon="26.0865814" [..]>
[..]
```

However, the tool that imports the OSM data to postgresql (`osm2pgsql`) defaults to re-projecting node coordinates:

```
$ ./osm2pgsql --help

This will import the data from the OSM file(s) into a PostgreSQL database
suitable for use by the Mapnik renderer

Options:
[..]
   -l|--latlong     Store data in degrees of latitude & longitude.
   -m|--merc        Store data in proper spherical mercator (default)
   -M|--oldmerc     Store data in the legacy OSM mercator format
   -E|--proj num    Use projection EPSG:num
   -u|--utf8-sanitize   Repair bad UTF8 input data (present in planet
```

If you use the `-l` option, the postgresql database will contain WGS84 coordinates (EPSG 4326).

Answer (score -1):

World Geodetic System 1984 is not a coordinate system. You can have coordinates Easting/Northing and Lat/Long both referenced to WGS84.

Comment: How might i do that? set the srs to 4236 on import?

Comment: @Holly - I believe you mean 4326 which is WGS84. OSGB is 27700. Anyway, I don't believe Spharios is being entirely clear; typically if something is in WGS84 then it'll be Lat/Lon. If its in OSGB then it'll be in metres (eastings/northings).

Comment: OSM use the Google Mercator projection SRID=900913 http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Projection

Comment: @Mapperz: No, OSM database stores WGS84 coords. The rendering toolchain (mapnik) is configured historically to use 900913 so the importer (osm2pgsql) defaults to re-projecting data to Mercator when creating a Postgresql database for rendering purposes.